# Function name must be a string in /var/www/html/fazrin/application/controllers/file.php on line 18

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, writetofile

```
class File extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('file');
    }

    function writetest()
    {
        $data = "Hello World!";
        $file= "application.DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.test_data.DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.helloworld.txt";
        $write_file($file,$data);
        echo "finished writing";
    }
```

This code shows the following error message in CodeIgniter:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: Write_file
>
> Filename: controllers/file.php
>
> Line Number: 18
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   /var/www/html/fazrin/application/controllers/file.php on line 18

This is line 18:

```
 $write_file($file,$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$write_file` is not variable it is a function of Codeigniter .You are treating the `write_file()` as varibable. So, you must remove `$` in `'$write_file($file,$data)` as below :

```
function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('file');
    }

    function writetest()
    {
        $data = "Hello World!";
        $file= "application.DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.test_data.DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR.helloworld.txt";
       write_file($file,$data);
        echo "finished writing";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't use $ in front of write_file($file,$data)